# Include other folders besides WEB-INF/classes in Maven Jar file?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

My pom.xml looks like this (note I'm building a JAR as well as a WAR):

```
            ...
            <packaging>war</packaging>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <containerConfigXML>src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml</containerConfigXML>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

However, the generated JAR only includes the classes in WEB-INF/classes. How can I get the JAR to include the classes in src/main/java/com/... etc as well - without having to add all the classes to the WEB-INF directory?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of packaging did you defined in your pom ? May be you can give a little bit more of your pom?

Comment: What is your goal actually? Don't break conventions. You obviously trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by removing the archiveClasses node from the above code sample. New pom.xml looks like this:

```
            ...
            <packaging>war</packaging>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <containerConfigXML>src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml</containerConfigXML>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Now the generated JAR includes all classes, not just those in WEB-INF/classes

Answer (score 0):

Generally if your resources are configured correctly (or standard layout) you should just be able to run

```
mvn package
```

Which should generate the jar file in your target directory.

Hope this helps.